# Can model.summarize() in Keras (Sequential) - Multi Input (Numerical + n Embeddings) work?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, keras-layer

I'm having difficulty printing the model.summary() after using the Sequential class in keras to build a structure like so:

```
embedding_inputs*   numerical_input
      \                   /
       \                 /
         -- CONCATENATE--
                 |
            DENSE (50) #1
            DENSE (50) #2
            DENSE (50) #3
            DENSE (50) #4
            DENSE (1)  #output


* embedding_inputs are a bunch of concatenated sequential models from 
categorical variables. For the sake of simplicity, 
let's pretend there is only one.
```

I know without the embedding layer(s), my model works and looks fine. But following my addition of an embedding layer and a concatenate layer, I'm told I need to build the model or that my Output tensors "must be the output of a Keras Layer."

I'm just utterly confused at this point. (I'm used to using the functional api but embarrassingly am having so much trouble with the Sequential one and would like to learn).

```py
categorical = Sequential()
categorical.add(Embedding(
    input_dim=len(df_train['mon'].astype('category').cat.categories),
    output_dim=2,
    input_length=1))
categorical.add(Flatten())

numeric = Sequential()
numeric.add(InputLayer(input_shape(1,len(numeric_column_names)),dtype='float32',name='numerical_in'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Concatenate([numeric,categoric]))

model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal')) #output layer (1 number)
```

If I attempt to use model.summary() without a build:
`ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling build() or calling fit() with some data. Or specify input_shape or batch_input_shape in the first layer for automatic build.`

If I attempt to use model.build() first, I get a message like:

`` ValueError: Output tensors to a Sequential must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: None ``

Comment: Why not make the whole model using the Functional API?

Comment: I'm being asked explicitly not to for this assignment ( :( )